# Logging ssh sessions using tee and parsing file for user commands

Tags: linux, logging, ssh

I need to log ssh session of every user from the client side. I'm using the tee to do this

`ssh abc@example.com | tee $(whoami).$(date).log`

However, I only want to log user commands within the ssh session and skip the output of the command. For eg: If a user tailed a large file, I don't want to log the entire file.

I tried to grep for the command prompt and redirect the output to another file.

`ssh abc@example.com | tee >(cat logfile) | grep "CMD_PROMPT_PATTTERN" >> $(whoami).$(date).log`

But this does not work if the user changes the command prompt.

I wanted to know if there was a way to grep for linux commands from a text file.

**Some related context**:
I have read other posts which suggest adding a wrapper around ssh to do the logging.
But in this case, users can ssh to another host(say example2.com) from example.com and  we need to log commands executed here as well from the starting host. I have also tried keystroke loggers but there is no way to distinguish commands executed by different users.

I'd appreciate any other suggestions to implement logging.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139874/local-timestamped-logging-of-all-ssh-commands

Answer (score 0):

Why not `tail -f` user's .bash_history ?  (or what shell they use), but 1st you will need to set "online" writing to it `export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'`